# refresh security.context in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have the following app flow:

Add role action:

```
 public function addroleAction($role) {
            $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $userId = $user->getId();
            $userObj = $em->getRepository('ProjectEntityBundle:User')->find($userId);

            switch ($role) {
                case 6://student
                    $userObj->addRole('ROLE_STUDENT');
                    $em->flush();
                    $securityContext->getToken()->setUser($userObj);
                    break;
            }
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('check_role'));
        }
```

Check role action:

```
public function checkroleAction() {

        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_STUDENT')) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student_profile'));
        } else {
            return $this->render('ProjectEduBundle:User:selectrole.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

The first action adds role to the database and redirect is made to checkroleAction.
The `if` condition is not met(returns false).
I guess this happens because security context is not refreshed after the database operation of adding role is done.
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user on the token again...

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->setUser($userObject);
```

Add that at the end of your `addroleAction()`

Comment: Tried. Does not work! Still returns false! I am creating new security context in every action! Is that a problem?

Comment: Creating a new context seems a bit alarming since it should be loaded from the session.

Comment: I use $securityContext = $this->get('security.context'); in every action. And use that variable throughout the action. Is that a problem?

Comment: @aBhijit you can try implementing the [`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) on your User entity, and return `false`  in the `isEqualTo` method if the roles on the provided `UserInterface` instance do not match the current user